# Error: Trying to pass data between activities in different applications of Intent in Android

Tags: android, android-intent

** Code used in First/Parent Activity of Application A

```
  Intent LaunchIntent = new Intent();
            LaunchIntent.putExtra("ComingFrom", "RentsComments");
            LaunchIntent.setClassName("packageNameOfApplicationB", "activityName");
            startActivityForResult(LaunchIntent, requestCode);


**Code used in SecondActivity:**

Intent launchIntent = new Intent();                
                launchIntent.putExtra("transaction_data_id", 123456);
                launchIntent.putExtra("transaction_data_authorised_amount", 10.0);
                launchIntent.putExtra("transaction_data_status", "finished");
               // launchIntent.setClassName("packageName", "fullQualifiedActivityNameInPackage");
                setResult(2520,launchIntent);

                finish();
```

I couldn't understand why the onActivityResult in ParentActivity is not firing once after calling it

Comment: Does SecondActivity have `launchMode=singleTask`?

Comment: Hi, it does have launchMode as singleTask

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `startActivityForResult()` when the target has the `singleTask` launch mode. Or rather, you can, but you will get an immediate `RESULT_CANCELLED`, not the actual result.

From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29):

> Note that this method should only be used with Intent protocols that
>   are defined to return a result. (...) For example, if the activity you
>   are launching uses the singleTask launch mode, it will not run in your
>   task and thus you will immediately receive a cancel result.

Unfortunately, there is no workaround for this (AFAIK).